# Vue - v model an object in a select tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select tag which is displaying an array of objects as its options. Within the option, I'm only displaying the name property of each object. I'm have a v-model on the select tag which defaults to one of the object's name property. My goal is to use id of the selected option in the watcher function. Here is some pseudo-code below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-model="selectedGame">
            <option v-for="(game,index) in selectedGames" :key="index + 'game'">{{ game.name}} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedGames: [
                {id: 1, name: "ABC"},
                {id: 2, name: "DEF"},
                {id: 3, name: "GHI"},
                {id: 4, name: "ABC"},
            ],
            selectedGame: "ABC"
        }
    },
    watch: {
        async selectedGame() {
            // I want make an async call using the id of the selected game
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

One solution I thought of which works fine is to search the array with the value of selectedGame (the var being v-modeled). That solution falls apart when I have two objects with the same name property (ABC for id 1 and 4).

I wish I could v-model the array, then have access to the selected object in the watcher, but I'm pretty sure vue doesn't work like that since the v-model has to be on the select, not the options.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the `game` object to `<option>.value`, so that the `<select>`'s `v-model` gets the object value of the selected game:

```html
<select v-model="selectedGame">
    <option v-for="game in selectedGames" :value="game">{{ game.name }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
export default {
    data() {
        const selectedGames = [
            {id: 1, name: "ABC"},
            {id: 2, name: "DEF"},
            {id: 3, name: "GHI"},
            {id: 4, name: "ABC"},
        ]
        return {
            selectedGames,
            selectedGame: selectedGames[0]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        async selectedGame(selectedGame) {
            await fetch('/api/select/' + selectedGame.id)
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-object-value-to-select?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: This is the exact solution! Thanks a lot!